# SQL Query: get adjusted value of each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several columns in a SQL table, and I would like to compute the result for each row in the table. My data looks something like this:

```
data
name     value   adjustor1    adjustor2
Comp1    20       0.05        0.08
Comp2    80      -0.07        0.065
```

The formula for the adjusted value for each row is:

```
adjusted_value = value*(1 + adjustor1)*(1 + adjustor2)*(100/sum(value))
```

So the adjusted output should be:

```
data
name     adjusted_value
Comp1    22.25
Comp2    77.75
```

The original values sum to 100, and the adjusted values should also sum to 100. I've tried things such as:

```
SELECT adjusted*(100/sum(adjusted)) 
FROM (
      SELECT value*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2) as adjusted 
      FROM data
) as result
```

which gives me the error: `ERROR: column "result.adjusted" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Although if I just do:

```
SELECT sum(adjusted) 
FROM (
       SELECT value*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2) as adjusted 
       FROM data
) as result
```

OR

```
SELECT adjusted
FROM (
      SELECT value*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2) as adjusted 
      FROM data
) as result
```

I can get either the sum OR the adjusted value, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name `value`  is not a good choice, it is a reserved word. I changed it to `val` instead.

This is the query you need:

```sql
WITH data(name,val,adjustor1,adjustor2) AS (
    VALUES
    ('Comp1'::text,20,0.05,0.08),
    ('Comp2',80,-0.07,0.065)
)
SELECT name,val,adjustor1,adjustor2,
       CAST(val*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2)*(100/sum(
         val*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2)
       ) OVER ()) AS numeric(10,3)) adjusted_value
  FROM data;
```

I must admit, it is a bit clumsy, sub-query makes it easier to understand ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2725)):

```
WITH data(name,val,adjustor1,adjustor2) AS (
    VALUES
    ('Comp1'::text,20,0.05,0.08),
    ('Comp2',80,-0.07,0.065)
)
SELECT name, CAST(adj*(100/sum(adj) OVER ()) AS numeric(8,3)) adjusted_value
  FROM (
    SELECT name,val,adjustor1,adjustor2,
           val*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2)  adj
      FROM data) s;
```

Some notes:

- Original `sum(adj)` is replaced with `sum(adj) OVER ()`, which is a syntax for [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html).
- I also added `[CAST()][3]` in order to round up the values.

Comment: I had been toying with the OVER(?) syntax for a while, but I couldn't figure out where to put it. That looks perfect and eliminates the need to duplicate the subquery, or do cross joins.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `SUM` in a subquery and then you can do `CROSS JOIN` to achieve what you want

```
SELECT name, 
       value*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2)*(100/T.adjSum) as adjusted_value
FROM data
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT SUM(value*(1+adjustor1)*(1+adjustor2)) as adjSum 
 FROM data) T
```